# Learning ReactJS - Good tutorial website for learning ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I had background with Angular/AngularJS I would like to learn ReactJS. 
Any suggestions what are the good documents/tutorials website that help developer to learn ReactJS?
Thanks
Kim

Comment: Home sweet home. `https://reactjs.org`

Comment: You should try google first before posting a question on here. Stack overflow is generally a place to answer questions about code, not to help find a tool / resource. Documentation first! :D

Answer (score 0):

i'm a React developer here, this was my first way out: [Beginners guide to react by Kent C Dodds](https://egghead.io/courses/the-beginner-s-guide-to-react)

Comment: that tutorial tells developers to make HTTP requests from components... eww. just be careful with what you recommend :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell As for beginners, almost every tutorial you see out there does this [From the official docs] (https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html). The component even if you make your API calls anywhere else you're still gonna have to load it into your component. Besides, you don't expect a beginner to worry about overhead.

Comment: Well what happens when your component is attached to a webpage. if you navigate to different pages that will mount different components which will kick off requests to happen on the component. If you navigate away / unmount a component while making a request exceptions can be thrown. Generally its better to use something like redux to manage state / handle requests

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying, Redux and its friends are not for beginners, the person is coming from Angular, suggesting something as confusing as Redux maybe a turn-off. He would learn how to use React first before they can consider an intermediate approach to managing state. He needs to learn how components work, how rendering and basic things work before they can learn about State management outside the local state. I agree that Redux is better for managing and handling request and managing state but damn that's another hurdle for a beginner@JohnRuddell

Comment: This course helped me a lot to start with react.. You should try it https://www.udemy.com/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/

Comment: Beginner stuff aside, you can use `AbortableControllers` instead of running straight to redux. Redux introduces its own complexities: Having to handle stale data over time, reusable components are forced to share the same state (as well as same state naming convention), and potential session bleeds (while staying on the same page, signing out of one account and signing into another). Here's an example of an abortable promise: https://ipq0f.codesandbox.io/ (open dev console -- navigate to form, quickly navigate to home, navigate back to form, wait, fill out form, submit & navigate back to home)